# Codeigniter pass value from URL

Tags: php, codeigniter

Function receives departure date and adult from view page ( it passes value correctly as I have checked doing echo function ) , but from this function I am not able to pass values to another function

```
public function index()
{

    if ($data = $this->input->post('muktinath')) {

        $date = $data['departure_on'];
        $adult = $data['adult'];

        $getNameValue = array(
            $date = 'departure_on',
            $adult = 'adult',
        );

        redirect('booking/muktinath/' . $getNameValue);
    }

    else{
        $this->load->view('index');
    }
}
```

This is the function which must receive the value

```
public function muktinath($getNameValue)
{
    echo $getNameValue; 

    // here value must be shown of departure date and adult passed from above

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't share the error messages you are getting. Bet there several.

The biggest issue is you cannot put an `array` as a part of your query string. But the fix is pretty easy.

```
function index()
{
    $data = $this->input->post('muktinath'); 
    if($data)
    {
        //From your question $data seems to be an array already. Just use that!
        redirect('booking/muktinath/'.$data['departure_on'].'/'.$data['adult']);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('index');
    }
}
```

Your function that receives the values is then defined this way.

```
public function muktinath($date, $name)
{
    echo $date . " - " . $name;
}
```

You **will have a problem** if `$date` contains any slashes (/) in what I assume is a date string. The slashes will become part of the URL which, if the date was "7/9/2016" and name was "sandesh" would make this URL.

`http://example.com/booking/muktinath/7/9/2016/sandesh`

As you can see, it has several more URI segments than you are expecting. This URL would echo "7 - 9" which is not very helpful. You might have to adjust the format of the date while sending it and then reformat it after it is received by  `muktinath()`.

By the way, your array declaration is wrong. I think you were trying to make this.

```
$getNameValue = array(
   'departure_on' => $date,
   'adult' => $adult
   );
```

The thing is, you have just recreated what `$data` already was. But you don't need `$getNameValue` anyway.

Comment: Ahh, you beat my answer by seconds, we cross posted. I was wondering why he would post data, collect it, and then redirect with that data. Why would he not just post to the controller that deals with the data in the first place, which would have to validate the segment data in the url yet again.

Comment: At least we agree on the solution so sandesh should feel confident it is the right answer. I figure there was code not shown that made his flow logical. IMO, session data would probably be more useful in this situation. But that doesn't answer the question of how to pass the value by URL.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this:

```
redirect('booking/muktinath/' . $getNameValue);
```

Try echoing out booking/muktinath/'.$getNameValue and you will see you have a array to string error. A redirect is a url, but you have got the data from a post. You cannot easily convert from a post to a url and you should not do so either, otherwise what was the point of posting the data in the first place. How do you know the post values do not have illegal url characters in them?

Why redirect at all, just post your form to the correct page in the first place and deal with the post data there?

Either validate, format for url and then use the actual components in your url call NOT like this but something like this....

```
redirect('booking/muktinath/'.$date.'/'.$adult);
```

Or better, do not redirect here but call a function (a library or a model or in your controller, that is up to you)

```
public function muktinath($date, $adult)
{
       ....
      return TRUE/FALSE or whatever you need.
}
```

And in your controller check the return value to see what to do

```
if ($this->mylibraryorwhatever->mukinath($date, $adult) 
{
    // success
    redirect('success page');  // or whatever
}
else
{
   // fail
   .....
}
```

Hope that helps.