# How to show redirect from controller using ID in PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, ajax, codeigniter

I have one button but it's like generate 2 function. I want save data and redirect to view before with ID. But, I've get the error in the syntax. `Message: Too few arguments to function c_transaksi::tambah_shrinkage(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\testresult\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 532 and exactly 1 expected`

here the controller

```
public function tambah_shrinkage($report_no)
    {
        $this->data['detail'] = $this->m_transaksi->get_by_reportmaterial($report_no);
        $this->data['shrinkage'] = $this->m_transaksi->get_shrinkage();
        $this->template->load('admin/layout/templatetesting','admin/transaksi/shrinkage/tambah', $this->data);
    }

 public function tambahaksi_shrinkage()
    {
        $jumlah_shrinkage = count((array)$this->input->post('nama_shrinkage_hidden'));

        $data = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i < $jumlah_shrinkage; $i++){ 
            array_push($data, ['nama_shrinkage' => $this->input->post('nama_shrinkage_hidden')[$i]]);
            $data[$i]['report_no'] = $this->input->post('report_no');
            $data[$i]['before_wash'] = $this->input->post('before_wash_hidden')[$i];
            $data[$i]['after_wash1'] = $this->input->post('after_wash1_hidden')[$i];
            $data[$i]['actual1'] = $this->input->post('actual1_hidden')[$i];
            $data[$i]['after_wash3'] = $this->input->post('after_wash3_hidden')[$i];
            $data[$i]['actual3'] = $this->input->post('actual3_hidden')[$i];
            $data[$i]['after_wash15'] = $this->input->post('after_wash15_hidden')[$i];
            $data[$i]['actual15'] = $this->input->post('actual15_hidden')[$i];
            $data[$i]['c_shrinkage'] = $this->input->post('c_shrinkage_hidden')[$i];
        }

        $this->m_transaksi->insert_shrinkage($data);
        
        redirect('c_transaksi/tambah_shrinkage');
    }
```

here the view button

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block bg-gradient-info" style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: 13px; color:aliceblue;"  onclick="history.go(-1);">SUBMIT</button>
```

I've tried using js history.back and ajax but still get the same error

here the ajax code

```
 $('#simpanshrinkage').on('click', function(){
              
                var currentRow =  $(this).closest("tr");

                const data_shrinkage = {
                    report_no : currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text(),
                    nama_shrinkage : currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text(),
                    before_wash : currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").text(),
                    after_wash1 : currentRow.find("td:eq(3)").text(),
                    actual1 : currentRow.find("td:eq(4)").text(),
                    after_wash3 : currentRow.find("td:eq(5)").text(),
                    actual3 : currentRow.find("td:eq(6)").text(),
                    after_wash15 : currentRow.find("td:eq(7)").text(),
                    actual15 : currentRow.find("td:eq(8)").text(),
                    c_shrinkage :currentRow.find("td:eq(9)").text()
                }

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "<?=site_url('c_transaksi/tambahaksi_shrinkage') ?>",
                    data:data_shrinkage,
                    success: function(data){
                       console.log("berhasil");

                       window.history.back();
                    }
                })
            })
```

Comment: check your redirect `tambah_shrinkage` in  `tambahaksi_shrinkage()` requires a parameter to be passed

Comment: Hi @Adi I've already check it and edit

Comment: where or rather which function this `redirect('c_transaksi/tambah_shrinkage');` code go to?

Comment: that function will go to detail, and inside detail there is another page for fill based on id @Adi

Comment: So you have a parameter for this function `tambah_shrinkage($report_no)` right? are you passing a parameter via `redirect('c_transaksi/tambah_shrinkage');`?

Comment: Yes, sure that's right but I get error message @Adi

Comment: so you need to pass `this->input->post('report_no')` from this `tambahaksi_shrinkage()` function in the redirect `redirect('c_transaksi/tambah_shrinkage');`

Comment: Can you show me how to pass ```this->input->post('report_no')``` from this ```tambahaksi_shrinkage()``` function in the redirect ```redirect('c_transaksi/tambah_shrinkage');``` ? @Adi

Comment: AJAX doesn't follow redirects, so even if you fix this it won't redirect you. Rethink your design.

Comment: You want the url in your javascript to be `url: "<?=site_url('c_transaksi/tambahaksi_shrinkage') ?>" + data_shrinkage.report_no,` right?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53944840/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/39375987/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/57945785/2943403

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you may imlement it like this:

1. your $.ajax POST should return proper json

   ```
    public function tambahaksi_shrinkage() {

        /* Do whatever you want here */

        echo json_encode(['success' => true]);

        // this is not what you want to do inline:
        // redirect('c_transaksi/tambah_shrinkage');

        exit;
    }
   ```
2. check for "success" in your handler and then do the redirect

   ```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "<?=site_url('c_transaksi/tambahaksi_shrinkage') ?>",
        data:data_shrinkage,
        success: function(data){
           console.log("berhasil");

           if(data.success) {
                window.location.href = "<?=site_url('c_transaksi/tambah_shrinkage') ?>";
                return;
           }

           // do something here if !data.success
        },
        dataType: 'json' // its a good habit to tell jquery what kind of response you expect
    });
   ```
3. remove the `$report_no` param from your `tambah_shrinkage` method and try to send it via GET-Param to your endpoint. I suspect the `$report_no` is something like your last_insert_id from your storage engine. So return it in your json and send it back to your endpoint as a GET-Param. Alternatively you may store it in `$_SESSION` and read it from `$_SESSION` in your endpoint but this depends on your usecase.

Comment: How does this solve the error? `Message: Too few arguments to function c_transaksi::tambah_shrinkage(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\testresult\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 532 and exactly 1 expected`, as long as the `tambah_shrinkage($report_no)` has a compulsory param

Comment: @Adi this does not solve the error. The error is trivial. I think the root problem is a complete missunderstanding about application flow of ajax requests and redirects. But i will edit my answer and add a hint about the missing argument. Thank you very much.